# select text after model change in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to select the text in a text input field after a model change, this is what I have so far:

I have tried something like this:`<input type="text" class="copyText" ng-change="onChange()" placeholder="" ng-value="toCopy" select-on-change readonly />` along with this

```
cdnApp.directive('selectOnChange', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
/*      scope.$watch('toCopy', function() {
            console.log(attrs);
            attrs.selectionEnd = 20;
        });*/
        element.bind('change', function() {
            this.select()
        })
    };
});
```

I have also tried setting up the input field like this `<input type="text" class="copyText" ng-model="toCopy" ng-change="onChange()" />`

and trying to act on it with this

```
$scope.onChange = function(a) {
}
```

But in this case I don't know how to first target the input field or how to get a reference to it in order to call the select() method.

I doubt that this is needed but this is the function that is changing the model, and it is being called by a click event on a series of buttons. Could it also be used to trigger a method that would act on every element that has this model?

```
$scope.sendToInput = function(w) {
    $scope.toCopy = w;
}
```

Comment: Could you make an example in http://plnkr.co/ showing what you have?

Comment: Why not `$watch`ing the model instead?

Comment: @CD can you explain how that would work? I thought about that but I wasn't sure for I could act on the input field based on that

Comment: just a POC: http://jsfiddle.net/8dZft/

Comment: @CD that did it. I tried something similar, not sure why it didn't work. Thank you so much